# Creating index page of posts in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

I am new to Symfony 2.7 and have limited knowledge of php.

I have a system whereby posts are created via the admin resulting in new pages.

I am trying to use these to create an index page showing all the current posts. Eventually this would probably just show title perhaps and i should be able to adjust the view but for now i'm trying to work out how do i get the posts to be got via the controller?

I've looked at the Symfony demo application but can't see how to adjust this to what i have - the annotation routing confuses me a little also as i am using YAML.

**Controller**

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

 /**
 * @param Post $post
 *
 * @return Response
 *
 * @ParamConverter("post", options={"mapping": {"name": "name"}})
 */

    public function viewAction(Post $post)
        {
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Post:view.html.twig', ['post' => $post]);
        }

}
```

**Routing**

```
my_results:
    path: /results/{name}
    methods: [ GET ]
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Post:view }
    requirements:
        name: \w+
```

So far I have add the extra routing...

```
my_indexresults:
path: /results
methods: [ GET ]
defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Post:index }
requirements:
    name: \w+
```

..and i have added to the controller...

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Post')->findAll();

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Post:index.html.twig', array('post' => $post));
}
```

Below is the relevant parts of index.html.twig , containing what I would use a loop of the posts, if i could tie up with the controller

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title="Posts Index">
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}
        <div id="{{ post }}">{{ post }}</div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

..but can't work out how to pull in the posts. If it's possible to tell without looking at the entity, how could I do this please?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, tell me after browsing this route /results

Comment: /results shows a view but won't show my posts until I do something in the controller. I have tried various things in `public function indexAction( here )` and with the mapping for this action but with differing errors

Comment: show code in your index.html.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your template expects 'posts' variable, but controller sends 'post'. Change `array('post' => $post));` to `array('posts' => $post));`

Also change `{{ post }}` to `{{ post.fieldName }}` in template.

Also u don't need any requirements in your 'my_indexresults' route.